# Can't remove readonly from a html select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically remove the 'readonly' attribute from some HTML elements.

I've created a [JSFiddle here][1] to show my issue, here is my code snippet:

```js
$('#theButton').on('click', function() {
  $('#mySelect').removeProp('readonly');
  $('#textInput').removeProp('readonly');
  //stop the form posting back
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Some input fields</label>
  <input type='text' class='form-control' id='textInput' readonly>
  <select id='mySelect' readonly class='form-control input-sm '>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    </select>
  <button class='btn btn-primary' id='theButton'>
    Enable Button
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: select readonly? maybe disabled? use `.prop()`

Comment: You can use [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) or [prop](api.jquery.com/prop/) and set your prop to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of [removeProp](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) is incorrect.

> The .removeProp() method removes properties set by the .prop() method.

Take a look what JQuery doc says:

> **Note:** Do not use this method to remove native properties such as
>   checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property
>   completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. **Use
>   .prop() to set these properties to false instead.**

You have to use [`prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) property to do this

> Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched
>   element.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go750egk/3/)

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('#theButton').on('click', function() {
  $('#mySelect').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#textInput').prop('readonly', false);
  return false;
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <label>Some input fields</label>
   <input type='text' class='form-control' id='textInput' readonly>
   <select id='mySelect' disabled class='form-control input-sm '>
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
   </select>
   <button class='btn btn-primary' id='theButton'>Enable Button </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I've tried running the snippet but it doesn't seem to remove the readonly flag.

Comment: @MrGiggles sorry there was a typo there in snippet check now

Answer (score 3):

You should use the attr function of jQuery:

```
$('#mySelect').attr("readonly", false);
$('#textInput').attr("readonly", false);
```

While using `prop` instead will work too, the [best practice](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) for your situation is to use `attr`.

Comment: Thanks, I used `.removeAttr('readonly')` and this has fixed the issue

Comment: @MrGiggles you shouldn't use `removeAttr` for property like this

Comment: Here,  **As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.**

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of jQuery's `.removeProp()` clearly states that it shouldn't be used to remove native properties.

> Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Use `.prop('readonly', false)` instead to make your textbox writable. Also, as @guradio suggested, [select boxes don't have readonly property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element). Please use `.prop('disabled', false)` to prevent users editing it.

More details [here](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/).